# How to execute a SPIN rule using RDF4J API on Ontotext GraphDB

Tags: java, graphdb, rdf4j

I am using RDF4J to create a repository on Ontotext GraphDB, import an RDF/XML to it and execute a SPIN rule.

We can create and configure the repository as shown here 
http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/using-graphdb-with-the-rdf4j-api.html

What is the proper configuration for SPIN support and the proper way to execute a SPIN rule on Ontotext GraphDB FREE or SE?
An example which would create the appropriate repository on GraphDB FREE or SE using RDF4J and executing an update sample SPIN rule (using RDF4J) on some sample data would be of great help.

Comment: Couple of things: 1) which version of GraphDB are you using, and which version of RDF4J? 2) the code snippet you show just creates an RDF4J memory store, not a GraphDB store - is this the _actual_ code you're using to set up your repo? 3) regarding the 'unsupported sail type' exception, that's something you can fix by including the `rdf4j-sail-inferencer` artifact. Though in combination with GraphDB you shouldn't need it as GraphDB itself supports RDFS inferencing natively.

Comment: Your comment helped a lot. I missed the configuration page on graphDB, worked just fine. I edited the post so that there is an easy to  find straight answer .

Answer (score 0):

GraphDB doesn't support SPIN rules. It only supports some SPIN functions: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data-using-ontorefine.html